# Distributions of two Markov chains

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

My question comes from reading a proof in a standard textbook on Markov Chains.

Let $X=\{X_n\}$ be an irreducible chain with period $d$. Let $Y=\{Y_n = X_{nd}:n \ge 0 \}$. Then $Y$ is an aperiodic chain.

Now suppose there exists some $m\le n$ s.t. $X_m=Y_m$. The textbook then says that, $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are identically distributed since the distributions of $X_n$ and $Y_n$ depend only upon the shared transition matrix $P$ and upon the shared value of the chains at the $m^{th}$ step.

---

My understanding and questions:

We know for any $0\le k \le n$, both $X_k$ and $Y_k$ can be represented by their transition matrices $P^k$ and $P^{kd}$, respectively. We also know $X_m=Y_m$ by assumption. Then what we can infer is merely $P^m=P^{md}.$

If $m$ is not a factor of $n$, i.e. $m \nmid n$, then we may not have $P^n=P^{nd}$ from $P^m=P^{md}.$ **Then why the textbook can conclude that $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are identically distributed?**

I guess the answer must have something to do with the sentence he wrote, *$X_n$ and $Y_n$ depend only upon the shared transition matrix $P$ and upon the shared value of the chains at the $m^{th}$ step*. The second half of the preceding sentence is somehow intuitive from the point of view of Markov property but I don't really understand it.

Comment: I think you are right. I don't believe that the book is right. Also, I understand the sentence:  Now suppose there exists some $m\le n$ s.t. $X_m=Y_m$. What is $n$ here?

Comment: @geetha290krm I think the n was fixed before the m-related sentence you mentioned. This should fine. I just don’t understand what does it mean by that $X_n$ and $Y_n$ depend only upon the shared transition matrix $P$ and upon the shared value of the chains at the $m^{th}$ step.